# Change background color of dynamically generated Div elements

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I am trying to altar the background color of dynamically generated div elements on a mouseover event.  I am still new to event listeners and feel I am lacking a fundamental concept on how they work.  How do I get them to apply to elements created after the DOM has loaded?

```js
const divSelector = document.querySelectorAll('main.child')
let gridSize = gridMaker();
let gridHover = colorChange();

function gridMaker () {
    let size = prompt('Enter a size: ')
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height = "100px";
        div.style.background = "red";
        div.style.margin = '10px';
        div.id = 'etch';
    
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
    }
}
//When mouse hovers over a div, permanently change color of that div
function colorChange () {
    divSelector.forEach((e) => {
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
            if (e.target.id == 'etch') {
                console.log('target found')
            }
        });
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener directly to div when you create it and add your logic to the callback.

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");
let gridSize = gridMaker();

function gridMaker() {
  let size = prompt('Enter a size: ')
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.style.background = "red";
    div.style.margin = '10px';
    div.classList.add('etch');
    div.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
      e.target.style.background = 'green';
    })
    main.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `const divSelector = document.querySelectorAll('main.child');` is run at the start of the script, at which point, there are no `<main>` elements with the `class` of `child` in the page. This means that `divSelector` will be an empty `NodeList`. So when `colorChange()` is called as the third statement, the `divSelector.forEach()` runs over an empty list and so the callback function is never run.

You shouldn't need the aforementioned `const divSelector = document.querySelectorAll('main.child');` statement or its later `.forEach()` call if you are going to be listening to `mouseover` on the `document`:

```js
let gridSize = gridMaker();
let gridHover = colorChange();

function gridMaker() {
  let size = prompt('Enter a size: ')
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.style.background = "red";
    div.style.margin = '10px';
    div.id = 'etch';

    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
  }
}
//When mouse hovers over a div, permanently change color of that div
function colorChange() {
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    if (e.target.id == 'etch') {
      console.log('target found')
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the problems with your existing code:

```
// this runs once, as soon as it's encountered by the
// JavaScript engine, and is never updated
// (document.querySelectorAll() returns a non-live
// NodeList); on page-load there are no matching elements:
const divSelector = document.querySelectorAll('main.child')

// the defined gridMaker() function returns nothing
// to the calling context; therefore this variable
// will always remain undefined:
let gridSize = gridMaker();
let gridHover = colorChange();

function gridMaker () {
    // there are no sanity checks to prevent anyone
    // from silliness, such as "" or "spaghetti"...
    // if you're accepting anything from a user assume
    // malicious intent:
    let size = prompt('Enter a size: ')

    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height = "100px";
        div.style.background = "red";
        // inconsistent style, this isn't a problem but
        // makes it easier to make typos in future, try
        // be sensibly consistent in your code (it makes
        // it easier to spot mistakes in future), but 
        // - as noted - it's not really a "problem":
        div.style.margin = '10px';

        // only one element can have a particular 'id,'
        // if you're creating multiple elements then
        // all elements will share this 'id' attribute-
        // value which is invalid HTML, and will cause
        // problems in JavaScript because of the
        // by-design functionality of getElementById()
        // querySelector() (though the latter can be
        // mitigated, but it's still bad practice):
        div.id = 'etch';

    // causes the page to be redrawn every time the loop
    // runs (browsers are quick, so you may not notice,
    // but it's a lot of work that can be avoided):        
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
    }
}

//When mouse hovers over a div, permanently change color of that div
function colorChange () {
    // will be a null value, which will generate errors:
    divSelector.forEach((e) => {
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
            // this should never be used; use either a
            // predictable "id" attribute-value style
            // or a class-name, with:
            // e.target.classList.contains(<className>)
            if (e.target.id == 'etch') {
                console.log('target found')
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Now, to address those problems you can either use event-binding at the point of element-creation, or you can use event-delegation. First, event-binding at the point of creation:

```js
// creating the named event-handling function:
const handler = (evt) => evt.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "hotpink",
  gridMaker = () => {
    // using the same prompt approach to obtain a user's desired number
    // of elements; we pass the result of that prompt() to parseInt()
    // which should return the integer (or NaN) from the result, having
    // parsed it to a base-10 format:
    let quantity = parseInt(prompt('How many elements should we create?').trim(), 10);

    // if no useful value was received, we quit here:
    if (!quantity) {
      return false;
    }

    // here we create a <div> element,
    let div = document.createElement('div'),
        // and a document fragment to prevent redraws:
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // we add the class-name, via the Element.classList API:
    div.classList.add('child');


    // we use Array.from() to create an Array:
    Array.from({
      // we pass in the retrieved value held in
      // the 'quantity' variable:
      length: quantity
    // we iterate over the Array, using
    // Array.prototype.forEach():
    }).forEach(
      // we pass in the index of the current Array-entry
      // (we also pass in a reference to the current
      // Array-entry, the '_', but this effectively
      // empty/undefined, so not useful):
      (_, index) => {

        // we clone the created <div> element:
        let clone = div.cloneNode();
        
        // set its id property (which is reflected in
        // it's attribute) to the string "etch_"
        // concatenated with the value of the "index"
        // using a template-literal String:
        clone.id = `etch_${index}`;
        
        // binding the event-handler - handler() - to
        // the 'mouseenter' event:
        clone.addEventListener('mouseenter', handler);

        // appending the cloned, and modified, element
        // to the document fragment:
        fragment.append(clone);
    });
    
    // appending the document fragment to the <main>
    // element:
    document.querySelector('main').append(fragment);
  };

// calling the function (after the function is declared,
// as using the const approach for function declaration
// prevents hoisting):
gridMaker();
```

```css
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.permaColor {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Next, event-binding; in which we bind the event-handler, as you were trying to do, to the existing ancestor element of those you wish to act upon:

```js
// finding the existing ancestor element:
const ancestor = document.querySelector('main'),
  handler = (evt) => {

    // using destructuring assignment to declare the variables
    // 'currentTarget' and 'target', and initialising them to
    // the values held in those property-names of the
    // Event Object passed into the function:
    let {
      currentTarget,
      target
    } = evt;

    // if the currentTarget (the element to which the event-handler
    // is bound) is the target (the element upon which the event
    // was initially fired), or the event-target element already
    // has the class-name we plan to add:
    if (currentTarget === target || target.classList.contains('permaColor')) {
      // we quit here
      return false;
    }

    // otherwise, if the target's list of class-names contains
    // 'child':
    if (target.classList.contains('child')) {
      // we add the 'permaColor' class:
      target.classList.add('permaColor');
    }

  },
  gridMaker = () => {
    // using the same prompt approach to obtain a user's desired number
    // of elements; we pass the result of that prompt() to parseInt()
    // which should return the integer (or NaN) from the result, having
    // parsed it to a base-10 format:
    let quantity = parseInt(prompt('How many elements should we create?').trim(), 10);

    // if no useful value was received, we quit here:
    if (!quantity) {
      return false;
    }

    // here we create a <div> element,
    let div = document.createElement('div'),
      // and a document fragment to prevent redraws:
      fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // we add the class-name, via the Element.classList API:
    div.classList.add('child');


    // we use Array.from() to create an Array:
    Array.from({
      // we pass in the retrieved value held in
      // the 'quantity' variable:
      length: quantity
      // we iterate over the Array, using
      // Array.prototype.forEach():
    }).forEach(
      // we pass in the index of the current Array-entry
      // (we also pass in a reference to the current
      // Array-entry, the '_', but this effectively
      // empty/undefined, so not useful):
      (_, index) => {

        // we clone the created <div> element:
        let clone = div.cloneNode();

        // set its id property (which is reflected in
        // it's attribute) to the string "etch_"
        // concatenated with the value of the "index"
        // using a template-literal String:
        clone.id = `etch_${index}`;

        // appending the cloned, and modified, element
        // to the document fragment:
        fragment.append(clone);
      });

    // appending the document fragment to the <main>
    // element:
    document.querySelector('main').append(fragment);
  };

// calling the function (after the function is declared,
// as using the const approach for function declaration
// prevents hoisting):
gridMaker();

// binding the event-listener to the 'ancestor' element:
ancestor.addEventListener('mouseover', handler);
```

```css
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.permaColor {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/px38bzhL/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`CSSStyleDeclaration.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText).
- [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- [Template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- [`window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).